# Does a router have only one BSSID?

Tags: wifi, router, rssi, bssid

In other words, can a router have more than one BSSID (for example, implementing two different versions of the 802.11 protocol)?

And if so, are the RSSIs from the BSSIDs of a specific router exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,you can have multiple BSSID on single router (or card) by making 
Multile VAP(virtual access point)
But , the RSSI should always be same for all new VAPs as RSSI depend on 
Tx Power (output power) ,thus can set one output power per chip (router).

you can change output power (RSSI) for different VAPs (BSSID) if it have more
than one Wlan Chip inside .